# failed to open the plugin manifest /.traefik.yml: open /.traefik.yml: no such file or directory

Tags: traefik

I'm new to Traefik. I'm trying to develop a plugin and "connect" it to my webserver using Docker Compose. I use docker compose for development. When I try to run the Docker Compose I encountered this error:

```sh
/dev/echo-docker-compose $ docker-compose up --build
Starting echo-server ... done
Recreating traefik   ... done
Attaching to echo-server, traefik
echo-server    | Echo server listening on port 8080.
traefik        | time="2022-03-18T07:40:11Z" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from flags."
traefik        | time="2022-03-18T07:40:11Z" level=info msg="Traefik version 2.6.1 built on 2022-02-14T16:50:25Z"
traefik        | time="2022-03-18T07:40:11Z" level=debug msg="Static configuration loaded {\"global\":{\"checkNewVersion\":true},\"serversTransport\":{\"maxIdleConnsPerHost\":200},\"entryPoints\":{\"traefik\":{\"address\":\":8080\",\"transport\":{\"lifeCycle\":{\"graceTimeOut\":\"10s\"},\"respondingTimeouts\":{\"idleTimeout\":\"3m0s\"}},\"forwardedHeaders\":{},\"http\":{},\"udp\":{\"timeout\":\"3s\"}},\"web\":{\"address\":\":80\",\"transport\":{\"lifeCycle\":{\"graceTimeOut\":\"10s\"},\"respondingTimeouts\":{\"idleTimeout\":\"3m0s\"}},\"forwardedHeaders\":{},\"http\":{},\"udp\":{\"timeout\":\"3s\"}}},\"providers\":{\"providersThrottleDuration\":\"2s\",\"docker\":{\"watch\":true,\"endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"defaultRule\":\"Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}`)\",\"swarmModeRefreshSeconds\":\"15s\"}},\"api\":{\"insecure\":true,\"dashboard\":true},\"log\":{\"level\":\"DEBUG\",\"format\":\"common\"},\"pilot\":{\"dashboard\":true},\"experimental\":{\"localPlugins\":{\"traefik-plugin-example\":{\"moduleName\":\"github.com/usergithub/traefik-plugin-example\"}}}}"
traefik        | time="2022-03-18T07:40:11Z" level=info msg="\nStats collection is disabled.\nHelp us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)\nMore details on: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/contributing/data-collection/\n"
traefik        | 2022/03/18 07:40:11 traefik.go:79: command traefik error: 1 error occurred:
traefik        |        * failed to open the plugin manifest plugins-local/src/github.com/usergithub/traefik-plugin-example/.traefik.yml: open plugins-local/src/github.com/usergithub/traefik-plugin-example/.traefik.yml: no such file or directory
traefik        | 
traefik        | 
traefik exited with code 1
```

I think I can conclude that the cause of this error is that it can't find the `.traefik.yml` file which is quite obvious. But, I already have the file in that directory.

This is my full directory structure

```
dev/plugins-local/
    └── src
        └── github.com
            └── traefik
                └── traefik-plugin-example
                    ├── plugin.go
                    ├── plugin_test.go
                    ├── .traefik.yml
                    ├── go.mod
                    ├── Dockerfile
                    ├── Makefile
    ├── traefik
    ├── traefik-plugin.go
    ├── rules-plugin.go
dev/echo-docker-compose/
    └── docker-compose.yml
    └── cmd
        └── ....
```

For some reasons, I think Docker Compose can't read `.traefik.yml`. But, it's also the same case when I try to run `./traefik --configfile traefik-plugin.yml` from `dev/plugins-local`. It also throws the same error where it can't read the `.traefik.yml`.

Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

This is the relevant codes:

On server repo

```yaml
# dev/echo-docker-compose/.env
PLUGIN_MODULE=github.com/usergithub/traefik-plugin-example
PLUGIN_NAME=traefik-plugin-example

# dev/echo-docker-compose/docker-compose.yml
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.6"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--experimental.localPlugins.${PLUGIN_NAME}.moduleName=${PLUGIN_MODULE}"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  echo-server:
    image: "usergithub/echo-server"
    container_name: "echo-server"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # The domain the service will respond to
      - "traefik.http.routers.echoserver.rule=Host(`echoserver.localhost`)"
      # Allow request only from the predefined entry point named "web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.echoserver.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.echoserver.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.echoserver.middlewares=echoserver-demo"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.echoserver-demo.plugin.${PLUGIN_NAME}.headers.DoesPluginWork=YES"
      - "traefik.http.routers.echoserver.tls.certresolver=default"
```

On plugin repo

```yaml
# dev/plugins-local/traefik-plugin.go
pilot:
    token: "token"

api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

experimental:
  localPlugins:
    traefik-plugin-example:
      moduleName: github.com/usergithub/traefik-plugin-example

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":8000"
    forwardedHeaders:
      insecure: true
  
providers:
  file:
    filename: rules-plugin.yaml
```

```yaml
# dev/plugins-local/src/github.com/usergithub/traefik-plugin-example/.traefik.yml
displayName: Traefik Example Plugin
type: middleware

import: github.com/usergithub/traefik-plugin-example

summary: 'Write plugin'

testData:
  userAgent:
    - Firefox
    - Mozilla/5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the [doc](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik-pilot/plugins/plugin-dev/), "There must be a .traefik.yml file **at the root** of your project describing your plugin" and from what I see in your directory structure, you placed .traefik.yml in the "src" folder with several sub folder in between.

Putting the file in the right place should solve the problem, please note that go.mod should also be at the root, (and the plugin must use git tag).

As an additional ressource, you can check [the demo plugin](https://github.com/traefik/plugindemo),

Also for anyone reading, I must add a disclaimer because Traefik plugins are still an "Experimental Features" and should be used with caution

Comment: so, the `.traefik.yml` should be in `/plugins-local/`? or is it under `dev`? but why does the error point out to the files inside `src/....`? i just tried moving it to the root but i still got the same error when running the docker compose.

Comment: according to the error on your first post `* failed to open the plugin manifest plugins-local/src/...`, the root is supposed to be at /dev ; Also I just saw that your first command was launched from /dev/echo-docker-compose, which means this is the working directory of the process running the traefik binary, according to the plugindemo repository, "The plugins must be placed in ./plugins-local directory, which should be in the working directory of the process running the Traefik binary." you should try to launch your docker from /dev, one can use `docker-compose -f` for this purpose